# WPF : A DataGrid sync B DataGrid With columnWith and DisplayIndex

Tags: wpf, datagrid

i used this link http://thibaud60.blogspot.com/2010/02/footer-on-wpf-datagrid-by-use-several.html to sync two DataGrid,but the Drag and drop column header sometime has bug.

A DataGrid has three column: A1,A2,A3

B DataGrid has three column: B1,B2,B3

I SetBinding like:

```
 Binding bindingWidth = new Binding();
 bindingWidth.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
 bindingWidth.Source = A1;
 bindingWidth.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridColumn.WidthProperty);
 BindingOperations.SetBinding(B1, DataGridColumn.WidthProperty, bindingWidth);

 Binding bindingDisplayIndex = new Binding();
 bindingDisplayIndex.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
 bindingDisplayIndex.Source = A1;
 bindingDisplayIndex.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridColumn.DisplayIndexProperty);
 BindingOperations.SetBinding(B1, DataGridColumn.DisplayIndexProperty, bindingDisplayIndex);
```

usually this work good,

but i changed A1 displayindex by drag the column sometime the two way binding is not work:

i drag A3 TO A1 position is not success , but B3 will success changed position to B1

the A1.DisplayIndex != B1.DisplayIndex ?

why that happen?

Answer (score 0):

i used

```
 private static Dictionary<DataGridColumn, DataGridColumn> ColumnCache=new Dictionary<DataGridColumn,DataGridColumn>();
```

to store the to DataGridColumn and

```
        dgSource.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged += (sender1, e1) =>
                {
                    var a=ColumnCache[e1.Column];
                    a.DisplayIndex = e1.Column.DisplayIndex;
                };
```

to change the columnDisplayIndex and the bug when i used binding like :

```
 Binding bindingDisplayIndex = new Binding();
 bindingDisplayIndex.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
 bindingDisplayIndex.Source = A1;
 bindingDisplayIndex.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridColumn.DisplayIndexProperty);
 BindingOperations.SetBinding(B1, DataGridColumn.DisplayIndexProperty, bindingDisplayIndex);
```

has resolve.
maybe there is some auto handle before the columnDisplay change

Answer (score 0):

I took some times to find the good approach, so for those who don't want search :-)
Thank you for your help

```
private static Dictionary<DataGridColumn, DataGridColumn> ColumnCache = new Dictionary<DataGridColumn, DataGridColumn>();
private static void SynchronizeVerticalDataGrid(DataGrid source, DataGrid associated)
{
    associated.HeadersVisibility = source.HeadersVisibility & (DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row);
    associated.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden;

    int sourceColIndex = 0;
    for (int associatedColIndex = 0; associatedColIndex < associated.Columns.Count; associatedColIndex++)
    {
        var colAssociated = associated.Columns[associatedColIndex];
        var colSource = source.Columns[sourceColIndex];
        sourceColIndex++;

        ColumnCache.Add(colSource, colAssociated);

        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        binding.Source = colSource;
        binding.Path = new PropertyPath(DataGridColumn.WidthProperty);
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(colAssociated, DataGridColumn.WidthProperty, binding);
    }

    source.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged += (sender1, e1) =>
        {
            var a = ColumnCache[e1.Column];
            a.DisplayIndex = e1.Column.DisplayIndex;
        };
}
```